# Reading specific XML element

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

We have a vendor company that requires the xml data files to have a specific layout. The structure is defined in the XSD file, and the structure can be updated (elements may be rearranged, or removed) every month (a new XSD file is sent out).

I have an XML file however, I need to have the elements laid out in the same order as the XSD requirements. Below is my code which can read the XML file. Based on my [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23675888/2570669) I am able to loop through the XSD file.

My problem is that I am not able to return a specific element from the xml file. How can I do that?

```
        foreach (var XSDsection in sections)
        {
            //Get Section Element;
            string SchemaSchedule = XSDsection.Attribute("name").Value;
            var SchemaSectionSchedule = XSDsection.Element(prefix + "complexType")
                                .Element(prefix + "sequence")
                                .Elements(prefix + "element");
            foreach (var schemaSection in SchemaSectionSchedule)
            {
                //Get child element;
                string schemaElement = schemaSection.Attribute("name").Value;
                var XMLsectionSchedule = xDoc.Descendants(SchemaSchedule);

                foreach (XElement element in xDoc.Element(SchemaSchedule).Descendants())
                {
                    string value = element.Value;       //returns value of next element;
                    string el = element.ToString();     //returns the next element and value from xml file;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not the best at XML, but I think you may be able to do something like this:

```
    foreach (var XSDsection in sections)
    {
        //Get Section Element;
        string SchemaSchedule = XSDsection.Attribute("name").Value;
        var SchemaSectionSchedule = XSDsection.Element(prefix + "complexType")
                            .Element(prefix + "sequence")
                            .Elements(prefix + "element");
        foreach (var schemaSection in SchemaSectionSchedule)
        {
            //Get child element;
            string schemaElement = schemaSection.Attribute("name").Value;
            var XMLsectionSchedule = xDoc.Descendants(SchemaSchedule);

            foreach (XElement element in xDoc.Element(SchemaSchedule).Descendants())
            {
                string value = element.Value;       //returns value of next element;
                string el = element.ToString();     //returns the next element and value from xml file;
                if(value == myDesiredValue)
                {
                    return element; // if you want the element, return it
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Note that this will return the first element that matches only. Once it finds it, it will return the element and stop looping through.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it out. Each element will occur only once in the data file.

Comment: You can also return the other elements in the parent loops, such as `return schemaSection;` or `return XSDSection;`.