# C# XML document remove elements that fail schema - preferably split the file into valid and invalid

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xsd

I have some user data coming out a system that needs to be fed into another as XML. There is an schema defined but the target system will accept the XML regardless of whether it passes or fails the schema, but instead fails silently.

I'm using a script component in SSIS and could write my own C# validation but I'm wondering if anyone can think of a way to validate the XML against the schema then split the XML into two files. One with valid users and another with invalid users? The XSD has custom types, Regex patterns etc. so I'd like to leverage what's already there if possible. I'm after an answer in C# preferably

```
<Users>
  <User>
    <FirstName/>
    <LastName/>
    <Etc../>
  </User>
</Users>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Users">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="User">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="FirstName" />
              <xs:element name="LastName" />
              <xs:element name="Etc.." />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thanks, I know how to validate the document. I know how to use Linq to XML, I'm after a neat solution to re-direct the invalid User elements, not just to tell me whether the document is valid or not.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "neat" solution for this - your problem is similar to those faced during xml interchange (or "batch") processing in messaging, where you may have failures half way through processing a batch, and how to recover from this.

The best way I can think of doing this is to convert your input data XML instance into lots of little XML instances, so instead of:

```
<Users>
  <User>
    ...
  </User>
  <User>
    ...
  </User>
</Users>
```

you just have a bunch of these:

```
<Users>
  <User>
    ...
  </User>
</Users>

<Users>
  <User>
    ...
  </User>
</Users>
```

Then you run validation against each of these XML instances and those that fail get "routed" to a handling process.

Appreciate this does not answer your question directly, but I can't think of a way of doing it when it's all one XML instance. The only thing which comes to mind is you could register a [ValidationEventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlvalidatingreader.validationeventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx), which will fire each time the validator encounters an error, and then handle each failure there, but it seems excessive.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm veering towards, splitting it out into individual XDocuments, validating them separately then merging them together...

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would:

1. Load the XML document into XDocument  (System.Xml.Linq)
2. Load the XSD into another XDocument ([hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421171/c-sharp-parsing-xsd-schema-get-all-elements-to-combobox))
3. Load all expected User elements from XSD into a List (let's call it Expected)
4. Load Users/User elements into another List (Let's call it UserNodes)
5. foreach User in UserNodes, check if All of node names in Expected is in User.
   -> Fails go to one list, Successes go to another
6. Use final Fails/Successes list to write two XML files

EDIT:

If your XSD patterns has a lot of different types to validate with (I mistakenly thought elements were the only issue), the best way is to use Tom's suggestion.

1. Load the initial XML Document.
2. Get all User elements and foreach User element to produce a new XDocument for each of them   (inserting it into parent elements so each one matches the XSD).
3. Add each produced XDocument to a List / HashSet.
4. Use this [MSDN Validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387037.aspx) tutorial to figure out which one matches the schema
5. I would still do as in my previous answer: to write fails on one list, successes to another, and then write to two different XML files.

Comment: Thanks, but what about matching the custom types, regex patterns, min occurs, min/max lengths etc. there's more to it than just confirming all the elements are there....

Answer (score -1):

I guess you want two things :

1.Validate XML

2.Split XML into valid and invalid users .

For 1 , it can be done Java as well . Please find this link 
http://www.journaldev.com/895/how-to-validate-xml-against-xsd-in-java for the same.

For 2 , valid and invalid users, you can use a XSLT to define your logic for segregating a valid or an invalid user .A java program can be written to run the XSLT .

Comment: Thanks, my logic is inside a C# script component so Java isn't an option. I could transform it with XSLT but to be honest it would be easier to just do it in C#. The schema has regex patterns, custom types etc. so it just feels like re-inventing the wheel doing it myself. I preferably want to leverage what is already there in the schema.

Comment: -1 This does not answer the question - firstly, the OP understands how to validate XML against schema, and secondly how can xslt be used to separate the valid from non-valid xml elements? The only time you would know when a user is valid is during validation, so are you proposing to dynamically build up the xslt based on validation failures?